# Select rows in a dataframe by date

Tags: python, pandas

For a given dataframe with a datetime column (2018-09-09 06:15:00), I would like to find all the rows that match a given date "2018-01-08".

I have tried something like this:

```
def get_connections(df, mydate):
    connections = df.loc[(df['dates']) == mydate]
    return connections
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
from datetime as datetime as dt
df['dates'] = df['dates'].apply(dt.fromisoformat)

def get_connections(df, mydate):
    connections = df.loc[df['dates'].apply(dt.date) == dt.strptime(mydate, '%Y-%m-%d')]
    return connections
get_connections(datestring)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"dates":["2018-09-09 06:15:00", "2018-01-08 06:15:00"]})

df[pd.to_datetime(df.dates).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").eq("2018-01-08")]
```

---

```
                 dates
1  2018-01-08 06:15:00
```